# Converting date field using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, date

I need to convert the date field in the feature class. The original date format is 15-Jan-2012, 27-Apr-2012, likewise.

How can I convert it into MM/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: You already accepted a Python answer.... but there is a tool that does this: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Field Calculator with Python parser. I calculate a new field but you can overwrite your original field if you want to.

```py
def convdate(f):
    from datetime import datetime
    dobj = datetime.strptime(f, '%d-%b-%Y') #Create a datetime object
    newdate = datetime.strftime(dobj, '%m/%d/%Y') #Convert back to string in the format you ask for
    return newdate

convdate( !datefield!) #Replace datefield with the name of your existing field
```

[image]

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

to understand the `'%d-%b-%Y'` etc.